# Why PLinq doesn't support more than 63 parallel threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, plinq

I think the question is clear. PLinq doesn't allow you to create more than 63 threads (WithDegreeOfParallelism doesn't allow it, throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException). In rare situations, we need to acquire more than 63 thread from thread pool (such as I/O operations, where a task needs more time to complete than usual). As far as I know, the Parallel class also has the same limitation. Is there any workaround? what's the reason for this limitation?

Comment: How many CPUs do you have?  Use APM for your (main) I/O operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoted from [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/186c1370-e140-4b39-b13e-0c403de4ddfb/):

> With Parallel.For/ForEach, there's no
>   implicit limit, however the ThreadPool
>   in .NET 4 (which Parallel.For/ForEach
>   target by default) will only use up to
>   64 logical processors.  PLINQ in .NET
>   4 does have hard-coded limit of 63
>   partitions.  As larger and larger
>   machines become available, I expect
>   you'll see such limitations removed,
>   just as how with the latest versions
>   of Windows the OS supports up to 256
>   logical processors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused here. The link says that Parallel.For/ForEach doesn't have thread limitation, however it also states that .NET ThreadPool (on which relies Parallel class) implementation does. This means that I'm still limited to 64 threads?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just created 525 threads via Parallel.ForEach.